# Tap UIButton and to call its action next view table cell row selected state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.2

i have button in mainView when i click mainview button(id 1) its actions to call nextView [secondview have tableView]  tableView cell first row selected or highlighted state.its state is set to selected.

```
-(IBAction)btnOneClicked:(id)sender
{
    SecondView *nextView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:SecondView animated:YES];
    NSIndexPath* selectedCellIndexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [nextView tableView:nextView.firstTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];
}
```

You can look at my  button action method. I have tried many options but with no success. Please help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndex:` is actually the delegate method called when you select a row.

To select the row, you need to call

```
[nextView.firstTable selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
[button_refresh addTarget:<instance where you want to implement the method> action:@selector(refreshContent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hope it will help you.